# How to create an array with a maximum size?

Tags: javascript, arrays, queue

I want to create a javascript array that won't ever have more than 5 elements, and that deletes any overflowing elements as a queue. My best idea so far is to override the array push method and check if the array's current length goes above 5, and if so, after adding the element, do an array.splice(0,1) to remove the last element. Is this the correct way on doing this?

Comment: `shift()` is probably more performant than `splice(0,1)`, but your algorithm seems solid.

Comment: I'd say to make your own array constructor that has a 5 element limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this work?

```
var myArr = [];

function arrayPusher(data) {

  //Add the data to the front of the array.
  myArr.unshift(data);

  //After adding the element to the array,
  //if it is too long, remove the last item.
  if (myArr.length > 5) {
    myArr.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see a situation where you lose control over your array but putting `array.length = 5;` in your length check function is much simplier. This will just remove anything after 5th element in one move.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think the best idea, is make a loop, re-using your function, like this:

```
function onlyN_Elements(N,vector){
   if(vector.length<=N){
       return vector;
   }else{
       vector.pop();
       onlyN_Elements(N,vector);
   } 
}
```

So always you wanna excecute this, just do this:

```
a = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];  //vector
N = 5                        //number of maximun length vector
onlyN_Elements(N,a);         // just execute the function

--> output --> console.log(a) --> a = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

So with this function just change 'N', if you wanna change your maximun length of your vector. ;)